# Database design in GAE/J : relational modelling vs entity-attribute-value

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling

Imagine you plan to create a social network **running on GAE/Java** where each user has a set of properties  (i.e. age, current town, interests).

**Alternative 1**: classical approach - the user_id and every property as a "row"

```
entity  property_1 property_2 property_3
------  ---------- ---------- -----------------
bob     missing    NY         [football, books]
tom     34         missing    [books, horses]
```

**Alternative 2**: entity-atributte-value (EAV)

```
entity   attribute   value
------   ---------   -----
bob      town        NY
bob      interests   [football, books]
tom      age         34
tom      interests   [books, horses]
```

What pros/cons do you think each option has?  My main concerns are:

1. What is the impact on multi-criteria searches (i.e. *"give me the users with ages under 45 that live in NY and like books"*)
2. What GAE/J implications could it have? (i.e. indexes, datastore size...)
3. How to model attributes with multiple values ("interests" for example) if you want to retrieve *"users that like books"* ?

I think the second alternative is more flexible and maybe easier to implement, but I would like to know what other experienced developers think.

Thank you.

Comment: Expando is the way to go, but you have to dig a bit to find out how to do it in java.

Comment: Thanks @Gabi, but the problem is not really that some properties are not mandatory. The problem is about what option is better in terms of 1. multi-criteria searches 2. GAE/J implications 3. properties with multiple values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you have a look at [Building Scalable, Complex Apps on App Engine](http://www.google.com/intl/nl/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) from Google I/O 2009? The video has terrible sound-quality, but it covers your topics. He talks about list properties and merge-joins and their limitations.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a corresponding just-plain-text-article for every talk, because it's more accessible for foreigners like me.

Comment: Well, there is a PDF containing the slides on that page, you've got subtitles on the YouTube video. You could even use Google Translate to translate the slides for you.

Comment: Thanks KRASH, there are a lot of very interesting videos about how Google datastore works.  The link you provide solves the 3 questions I asked.  For what I've seen, my alternative 1 seems to be the best option.

Answer (score 1):

If the flexibility of EAV is essential for your app then use it, otherwise do not since it'll have pitfalls in querying.

Will return all entities that have books in interests:

```
final Iterator<EAV> eavs = Iterators.transform(
    datastoreService.prepare(
        new Query(EAV.class.getSimpleName()).addFilter("a",
            FilterOperator.EQUAL, "interests").addFilter(
            "v", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "books"))
        .asIterator(), new Function<Entity, EAV>() {
      @Override
      public EAV apply(final Entity input) {
        return new EAV(input);
      }
    });
while (eavs.hasNext()) {
  logger.debug("eav: " + eavs.next());
}
```

Trying to fetch entities that have books in interests and aged under 45, but won't result anything since no row will have the two values of `a` and `v`:

```
final Iterator<EAV> eavs = Iterators.transform(
    datastoreService.prepare(
        new Query(EAV.class.getSimpleName()).addFilter("a",
            FilterOperator.EQUAL, "interests").addFilter(
            "v", FilterOperator.EQUAL, "books").addFilter("a",
            FilterOperator.EQUAL, "age").addFilter(
            "v", FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, 45))
        .asIterator(), new Function<Entity, EAV>() {
      @Override
      public EAV apply(final Entity input) {
        return new EAV(input);
      }
    });
while (eavs.hasNext()) {
  logger.debug("eav: " + eavs.next());
}
```

The result isn't surprising, as the querying in big table is not even close to the flexibility of SQL (no joins for example). The working solution would probably be multiple queries and manually combining and parsing their results.

OTOH with "classical approach" it's trivial:

```
final Iterator<Person> persons = Iterators.transform(
    datastoreService
        .prepare(
            new Query(Person.class.getSimpleName())
                .addFilter("interests",
                    FilterOperator.EQUAL, "books")
                .addFilter("age",
                    FilterOperator.NOT_EQUAL, null)
                .addFilter("age",
                    FilterOperator.LESS_THAN, 45))
        .asIterator(), new Function<Entity, Person>() {
      @Override
      public Person apply(final Entity input) {
        return new Person(input);
      }
    });
while (persons.hasNext()) {
  logger.debug("person: " + persons.next());
}
```

This will print out tom's data.